# How to partition amplify S3 storage by prefixing bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

At first, I want to setup multiple S3 storage in my amplify project.
But this is not allowed for now (amplify-cli shows me `Amazon S3 storage was already added to your project.`)

And I found the possible solution for my use-case by creating partitions.
This is mentioned in the link below.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1923#issuecomment-516508923

This says like follows.

```
As a best practice, the Amplify Framwork allows you to have multiple prefixes in the bucket as a best practice instead of having multiple buckets.
You could partition your bucket by prefixes like the following:
`mybucket/partition1` and `mybucket/partition2` which can potentially have different auth policies and lambda triggers.
```

But it didn't explain how to setup partitions and how to use it.
So, could anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder amplify/backend/storage/s3-cloudformation-template.json you can add a new policy for your new prefix, which will be the foldername in the s3 bucket

```
        "S3AuthStorage1Policy": {
            "DependsOn": [
                "S3Bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": "CreateAuthStorage1",
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": {
                    "Ref": "s3Storage1Policy"
                },
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "authRoleName"
                    }
                ],
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": {
                                "Fn::Split" : [ "," , {
                                    "Ref": "s3PermissionsAuthenticatedStorage1"
                                } ] 
                            },
                            "Resource": [
                                {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "",
                                        [
                                            "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                            {
                                                "Ref": "S3Bucket"
                                            },
                                            "/storage1/*"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js#using-amazon-s3
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/332#issuecomment-602606514

Now you can use e.g. the custom prefix "storage1" to store your files in a storage1 folder.

```
Storage.put("storageTest.png", file, {
  contentType: "image/png",
  level: 'public',
  customPrefix: {
    public: "storage1/"
  }
})
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

};

Do the same with another prefix (in this example storage 2) than you can store files from another use case in another folder.

[image: s3 bucket with two custom prefixes]